# How to see the current path in linux shell using c++?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am creating a shell program that has the ability to change directories and exit the shell. Everything is working as it should. I have a question about showing the current directory/path that I am in. When I compile & run my code. I am in my shell loop. My cursor represents **ash >** I want that cursor to represent the current path that the user is in.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ash_exit(char **args);
int ash_cd(char **args);

char const *builtin_str[] = {
    "exit", "cd"};

int (*builtin_func[])(char **) = {
    &ash_exit, &ash_cd};

int ash_num_builtins()
{
    return sizeof(builtin_str) / sizeof(char *);
}
/**
   Bultin command: change directory.
   args List of args.  args[0] is "cd".  args[1] is the directory.
   Always returns 1, to continue executing.
 */
int ash_cd(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ash: expected argument to \"cd\"\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (chdir(args[1]) != 0)
        {
            perror("ash");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int ash_exit(char **args)
{
    return 0;
}

int ash_launch(char **args)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // Child process
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
        {
            perror("ash");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid < 0)
    {
        // Error forking
        perror("ash");
    }
    else
    {
        // Parent process
        do
        {
            waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }

    return 1;
}

int ash_execute(char **args)
{
    int i;

    if (args[0] == NULL)
    {
        // An empty command was entered.
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ash_num_builtins(); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0)
        {
            return (*builtin_func[i])(args);
        }
    }

    return ash_launch(args);
}

char *ash_read_line(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    ssize_t bufsize = 0; // have getline allocate a buffer for us

    if (getline(&line, (unsigned long *)&bufsize, stdin) == -1)
    {
        if (feof(stdin))
        {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // We recieved an EOF
        }
        else
        {
            perror("readline");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return line;
}

#define ASH_TOK_BUFSIZE 64
#define ASH_TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"
/**
   Split a line into tokens
   line The line.
   return Null-terminated array of tokens.
 */
char **ash_split_line(char *line)
{
    int bufsize = ASH_TOK_BUFSIZE, position = 0;
    char **tokens = (char **)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char *));
    char *token, **tokens_backup;

    if (!tokens)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ash: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    token = strtok(line, ASH_TOK_DELIM);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        tokens[position] = token;
        position++;

        if (position >= bufsize)
        {
            bufsize += ASH_TOK_BUFSIZE;
            tokens_backup = tokens;
            tokens = (char **)realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char *));
            if (!tokens)
            {
                free(tokens_backup);
                fprintf(stderr, "ash: allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, ASH_TOK_DELIM);
    }
    tokens[position] = NULL;
    return tokens;
}

void ash_loop(void)
{
    char *line;
    char **args;
    int status;

    do
    {
        printf("ash > ");
        line = ash_read_line();
        args = ash_split_line(line);
        status = ash_execute(args);

        free(line);
        free(args);
    } while (status);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ash_loop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: See `man 3 getcwd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getcwd(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) gives you the current path:

```
    char buf[PATH_MAX] = {0};
    getcwd(buf, sizeof buf);
    printf("ash %s > ", buf);
```

Need to include `<linux/limits.h>` for `PATH_MAX`.